# I get error message "Crystal Report has stopped working " just for 1 report only, all the rest of my reports work fine

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I use Crystal Reports XI (11.5.12.1838) and windows 7 ; 
I can open all the crystal report files except 1 report,I get error message

> Crystal Report has stopped working
>    A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. 
>   Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available"

I tried to

1. Reboot my PC .
2. Checked the Datasource and ODBC connection, all work fine.
   3.in Crystal Report properties set the compatiblity mode to XP.
3. Unchecked the save the report with data in crystal report properties 
   but it still didn't help.

My other colleague can open the report on which I get error and they are using XP

Comment: do you have a version of the report that does work or has this report never worked on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

If he is on XP and it works for him while it crashes for you on Windows 7, I would suspect that you need to update your CR XI to the latest service pack from SAP. But since it's only a single report that is giving you grief it may not have anything to do with that. If it is not a very complex report, try recreating it or create a test report that is using the same data connection.

Answer (score -2):

If it works for him and not for you, check to make sure you have the drivers for the right version.

Someone might have put the 32 bit drivers on a 64 bit version on windows 7.